# NullPointerException in executeWithListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get PhotoUrl in this method.

```
  private String getUserPhotoUrl(String vk_id){
    final String[] url = new String[1];
    VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, vk_id,
            VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100"));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    VKList<VKApiUser> User = (VKList<VKApiUser>) response.parsedModel;
                    url[0] = User.get(0).photo_100;
                    Log.i("PhotoUrl", url[0]); //working perfect
                }}.start();
        }});
    return url[0];
}
```

In the  `Log.i("PhotoUrl", url[0]);` it gives not null. I mean normal url. **But** when I try to return it in `return url[0];` part, it gives me null. Any ideas?

Comment: there are 2 concurrent execution paths when you start new thread, you should use callback to post results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of concurrency. Your method immediately returns without waiting for any other thread.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement is outside the listener, and thefore returns befofre listener end processing.

So it returns a null